# How to read a file from one line to the end and write another from that same line to the end?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, readfile, writefile

```py
print("Type: \n 1 - To read and translate from the beginning of the file\n 2 - To read from a specific line of the file")
how_to_read = str(input())

if (how_to_read == "1"):
    read_mode = "w"
    total_previous_lines = 0 #Read the file from the beginning
elif(how_to_read == "2"):
    read_mode = "a"
    with open('translated_file.xml') as last_translated_file:
        total_previous_lines = sum(1 for line in last_translated_file) - 1  #Number of lines, to which one is subtracted for the last line that is empty and must be replaced from it if it is the case
        print(total_previous_lines)
else:
    print("You have not chosen any of the valid options")
    read_mode = None

if(read_mode):
    with open("en-sentiment.xml", "r") as read_file:
        #I NEED TO READ "en-sentiment.xml" FROM total_previous_lines + 1 (that is, the next to the last one that already existed, to continue...)

        with open("translated_file.xml", read_mode) as write_file:
            # I NEED TO WRITE "translated_file.xml" FROM total_previous_lines + 1 (ie the next to the last one, to continue...)

            #For each line of the file that it reads, we will write the file with the write function.
            for line in read_file:
                print(repr(line))
```

That's my code, and I was having trouble reading the .xml files from that `total_previous_lines`, since the statement `with open() as ..._file:` naturally reads from the beginning iterating line by line, but in this case if the file already existed, if with the opening mode a you wanted to write from `total_previous_lines` you would have the problem that it starts to iterate from the beginning.

And with the opening mode `"r"` the same thing would happen if you want to read from `total_previous_lines` with a value other than 0 (that is, the first line)

Comment: You can't process XML on a line-by-line basis. XML's integrity is not defined by lines. You can have a 1 MB XML document in just one line and you can have a single XML node span 10 lines.

Comment: @ThomasWeller In this particular case if I have been able to do it, that is why I need to be able to read from n line, being that n a numerical value stored in the variable called `total_previous_lines`. At the moment I only needed how to read and write from a line for example, line 50 until the end of the file

Comment: Notwithstanding the potential issues around accessing specific lines in an XML file (without properly parsing it) you can aways call readlines() on the open file handle. That gives you a list which you can access just like any other list by index

Comment: @OlvinRoght in this case I only read rows to be able to translate them, and I am also using a regex system to determine what to translate and what not, so the main problem is how to read from a certain line to the end and then how to write from that same line to the end in the other file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the code in your question...

Let's say that by some means or other you have figured out a line in your input file that you want to start reading from and that you want to copy the remainder of that input file to some other file.

```
start_line = 20 # for example

with open('input_file.txt') as infile:
    with open('output_file.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile.readlines()[start_line:]:
            outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Just one doubt, when you use the with statement for writing instead of "w", I think it would be convenient for me to put "a", since I think that way I would not lose the previous n lines

Comment: Fine, use 'a' if you want to append to an existing file. Also, mode 'a' will create the file if it doesn't exist

Answer (score -1):

Read about seek() in python. But better use an xml parser like ElementTree.

Comment: seek() isn't going to be very helpful for line-oriented data

Comment: @Teo So if I put `read_file.seek(20)` , this program already be reading from line 20 to the end of the file? And in the case of writing, I am using a for loop, and it would be complicated to use that seek

Comment: seek(20) moves the current offset into the file by 20 bytes - not 20 lines